# Downloaded jbcrypt, how do I install it in an existing netbeans project?

Tags: netbeans, jbcrypt

Downloaded here: http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/

Now I have a jbcrypt file, how do I import it into my existing netbeans project?

Googled for a bit but couldn't find anything on how to do this.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/6cxzbo/can_anyone_help_me_installsetup_jbcrypt_into_an/ You may have asked the question in the above link also but in case anyone else is looking for it

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **IntelliJ Idea 2019**, create a folder **"BCrypt"** which will contain that **"BCrypt.java"** file. Now copy and paste that folder *(containing that BCrypt java file)* in your project source directory and make the following changes. Open the BCrypt.java file and change **package org.mindrot.jbcrypt;** to **package BCrypt;** *(it is the very first line of the code)* now you can import BCrypt using import statement *(import BCrypt;)*.
Here's an image how I did it, **I hope this might work for Netbeans as well**.

[image]